# Elasticsearch- Combine Updates In a Script?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have many types of updates i'm making to documents in my Elasticsearch cluster. Most of them (by volume) are upserts. But `script` updates are becoming more common as there are many situations where I need to increment a value or push an item to an existing array. This means a single action may create multiple updates, a mix of upserts and scripts, that are applied in a bulk update.

We have a high volume of updates (hundreds of millions per day) on existing documents, so i'm becoming concerned about the overhead of making lots of small updates instead of large upserts. I'm also concerned that script updates aren't as optimal as upserts.

But even though I'm concerned about the performance of script updates themselves, would it make sense to combine these updates that require a script *into* the script itself?

For example. A user may visit a page and I want to update their last_seen date as well as their navigator and language. I also want to increment the number of times i've seen this user. To do this i'll use 2 updates-

```
# Update 1
{
  "_op_type": "update",
  "doc": {
    "last_seen": "2020-05-05 15:37:18",
    "navigator": "chrome",
    "lang": "en-us"
  }

}

# Update 2
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
       ctx._source.total_visits += 1;
    """
  }
}
```

Would it be more efficient (for elasticsearch) to do this all in the script update?

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
       ctx._source.last_seen = new Date();
       ctx._source.navigator = params.navigator;
       ctx._source.lang = params.lang;
       ctx._source.total_visits += 1;
    """,
    "params": {
      "navigator": "chrome",
      "lang": "en-US"
    }
  }
}
```

My assumption is that the script applies all the changes in memory prior to applying it to the indexes/ssd. If that assumption is correct, then my thought is, if i have to apply an update via a script anyway, I might as well combine them? Or, because i'm using a bulk update and/or a write queue exists, does it even matter that I have so many small updates if they are all applied at relatively the same time?

Comment: have you timed both solutions on a test index (similarly sized as your production one) to see which one is faster?

Comment: @Val That was going to be my next step. I wasn't sure if this was common knowledge or something I needed to test. I'll give a shoutout when I have results (but I may not be able to get to it today)

Comment: Every context is different and difficult to compare. We can advise on how to get better performance *given a specific context*, but otherwise it's hard to compare with nothing.